# JavaScript: Можно ли сделать перенос строки в качестве разделителя в Array.join()

Tags: javascript

Есть массив [1, 2, 3, 4]. Хочу превратить в строку чтобы разделителем был перенос строки.
Пробовал `Array.join('\n')`, `Array.join('<br>')`. Оба способа не работают. Вывожу через Vue.js.
Есть какой то способ вставить перенос строки в качетве разделителя в join?

Comment: если бы выводили через обычный html - все бы отработало через `Array.join('<br>')`

Answer (score 1):

Всё должно джойниться и выводиться. Главное - выбрать правильный вариант:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

document.getElementById("br-html").innerHTML = arr.join('<br>');
document.getElementById("br-txt").innerText = arr.join('<br>');
document.getElementById("br-cont").textContent = arr.join('<br>');

document.getElementById("nl-html").innerHTML = arr.join('\n');
document.getElementById("nl-txt").innerText = arr.join('\n');
document.getElementById("nl-cont").textContent = arr.join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="br-html" style="color:#f00;"></div>
<div id="br-txt" style="color:#F5CC00;"></div>
<div id="br-cont" style="color:#14D2AF;"></div>

<div id="nl-html" style="color:#BE06EC;"></div>
<div id="nl-txt" style="color:#8DBF14"></div>
<div id="nl-cont" style="color:#F48024;"></div>
```

Comment: автор vue.js использует

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь. Выяснилось, что во Vue.js выводить надо через v-html. 
`<span v-html="row.item.limits"></span>`
Работает этот способ `Array.join('<br>')`